# Web service Drupal 8 using Guzzle

Tags: 8

I'am working in web services in Drupal 8 using Guzzle.
I found the information how to GET and POST the node but the **PATCH( update the node) and the DELETE** , i did not find it.
The configuration in the `rest.settings.yml` is correct, the permissions are also good configured  and all modules are activated.
I have a doubt in the uri in patch. So there is my code in the controller.

```
public function guzzlePatchExample() {
    // Prepare entity data.
  $serialized_entity_to_modify = json_encode([
    'title' => [['value' => 'title modified with rest']],
    'body' => [['value' => 'body modified with rest ']],
    'type' => [['target_id' => 'article']],
    '_links' => [
      'type' => [
        'href' => 'http://example.com/rest/type/node/article'
      ]
    ],
  ]);
  // Modify the Node.
  $response = \Drupal::httpClient()
    ->patch('http://example.com/node/1', [
      // Username and password for HTTP Basic Authentication.
      'auth' => ['admin', 'anis'],
      'body' => $serialized_entity_to_modify,
      'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/hal+json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/hal+json'
      ],
    ]);
  // Check for the correct status code.
  if ($response->getStatusCode() == 204) {
    drupal_set_message($this->t('Node modified successfully!'));
    return $this->redirect('system.admin_content');
  }
   return array(
      "#markup" => "Hello PATCH with Guzzle",
    );
  }
```

Thanks for response.
Matio89

Comment: What status code is the patch request returning? And what's the body content?

Comment: The status code returning is 403 ( Forbidden) despite the authentication parameters are correct.
the node/1 body has any content. What's mean the body content ?

Comment: As in `$response->getBody()` (but if you're getting a 403 that probably won't be useful). Are you able to debug on the server? That would be the best thing to do, you'd be able to find out what it's objecting to